# How to get/pass a selected item from a html dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arguments

I'm trying to obtain the selected menu item from a ul dropdown list, but I'm not sure how to use PHP or JS to obtain the selected item.

The selected item needs to be submitted to the server-side with PHP. I know how to do it with a  menu, but I need to use a `ul` with `li` items for my current CSS to work.

```
<div class="TypeListBox">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
        <span>Food</span>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pizza-slice"></i></i>Pizza</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pepper-hot"></i></i>Mexican</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i></i>Burgers</a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the ability to pass the selected item i.e. "pizza". How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet

```
 <div class="TypeListBox">
   <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
    <span>Food</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="functionABC('Pizza')"><i class="fas fa-pizza-slice"></i></i>Pizza</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="functionABC('Mexican')"><i class="fas fa-pepper-hot"></i></i>Mexican</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="functionABC('Burgers')"><i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i></i>Burgers</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function functionABC(selectedElement){
        alert(selectedElement);
    }
</script>
```

You can use an input type `hidden` field to track the value of selected

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected" id="selected" value="" />
```

and change the selected value inside function `functionABC`

```
document.getElementById("selected").value = selectedElement;
```

Comment: Where would I place the hidden snippet? And what is the alert method used for?

Comment: Also how would I pass the selected element to PHP? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @Emil as I said to use the hidden field value in the post